# CORS Error while redirecting to external URL in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, node-modules

I have a node js application
I have made the below configurations in my index.js file

```
const app = express();
var cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "*" }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

In my API I am trying to redirect to an external URL like below

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let url = "https://externalurl.com";
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.redirect(encodeURI(url));
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.redirect(encodeURI(url));
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: err });
    }
}
```

But it is giving me the below CORS error

How do I fix it? Please help

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://externalurl.com' (redirected from 'https://myapplication/apis/v1/login/loginAuthentication') from origin 'https://myapplication.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Why are you repeating `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); res.redirect(encodeURI(url));` twice?

Comment: Because the code which I have written in index.js was not working

Answer (score 0):

You can't trick a browser into treating `B.com` has having granted permission with CORS by making a request to a CORS-enabled `A.com` and then redirecting to `B.com`.

`B.com` has to explicitly grant permission itself.

Comment: It cannot be done. Cannot make changes in external server.

Comment: @RajithaGanjiIN – Then you can't make the browser fetch data directly from it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because we at you node server you have to allow the resource sharing between the other platform .

For better understanding you can refer the video which resolve the issue with in 1 minute.

https://youtu.be/BVwZAr04bkc

if still not solved then let me know lets solve it together.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33164272)